# Odd behavior when saving a product model that has tier pricing from a script in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am finding some odd behavior when I try to save a product model from a script it Magento Enterprise 1.8 that has tier pricing.

Take this code for example:

```
// This product has a tier price
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(194760);
$product->setName('Changed Product Title');
$product->save();
```

When saving a get an exception (detailed below). However if I change nothing in the model, I do not get the exception. I have a feeling that this is due to the fact that I did not update anything so Magento does not do as much work.

```
// Same product, but I changed nothing and it works 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(194760);
$product->save();
```

The odd part is that I am able to save the product successfully if I am setting or modifying tier price information (pending I do not create anything that is duplicated)

```
// This works pending the tier price does not already exist
$mud_array = array();
$mud_array[] = array(
    'website_id' => 0,
    'cust_group' => 32000,
    'price_qty' => 5,
    'price' => 6
);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(194760);
$product->setTierPrice($mud_array);
$product->save();
```

The exception that I am seeing is as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '194760-1-0-5.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_TIER_PRICE'' in /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php:61

So it appears that when a tier price exists in a product, and you try to change anything inside the model, it will attempt to reinsert all the tier price information.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a way to work around this? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I created a fix for this that seems to work.

In /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice.php there is a function called savePriceData. From what I can gather this function is responsible for determining if we need to update or insert a tier price.

There is an if block that makes this decision to update or insert based on the information coming from the $priceObject that is passed to the function.

If you are updating a tier price from the admin panel, priceObject has two values value_id and value. These fields both point to columns in the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table. This is what happens in the first part of the if block

If you are creating a new tier price from the admin panel, priceObject has all the columns from the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table (entity_id, all_groups, customer_group_id, qty, value, and website_id). Magento then takes this information and inserts it into the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table.

The actual problem was that when you save a product from a script (aka outside the admin panel) you ALWAYS get a priceObject that contains all the information for an insert. So it will always try to do the insert into the table which if it already exists causes an integrity constraint violation.

So the fix I put together for this was really quite simple. In the second part of the if block, I am doing a check to see if the tier price already is in the table and if it is, I simply do not do the insert. Here is the code:

```
... first part of if statement
// somehow we need to have this not happen if it already exists
$reader = $this->_getReadAdapter();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_tier_price WHERE ";
foreach($data as $index => $value) {
$sql .= $index . ' = ' . $value . ' AND ';
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
$search = $reader->fetchAll($sql);
if(count($search) > 0) {
// It already exists, don't do anything
} else {
$adapter->insert($this->getMainTable(), $data);
}
```

Obviously, you really should make sure that you copy this file to local before you make this change (or probably better yet, rewrite it in a module). This probably is not the most 100% correct "Magento way" to do this, but I really needed to get a solution for this ASAP.

I am open to better solutions than this, but I wanted to share what I found

(Note: As I am on the Enterprise Edition of Magento, I did not want to share anymore of the source than necessary since it could be a violation of our license agreement)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with EE 1.12, but with the "group_price" attribute. Just managed to fix the error by adding at the begging of my script

> Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

Comment: Yes this works. I had a weird behaviour too. I was trying to update a product attribute, but existing tier prices on the product kept duplicating. Setting this prior to product update prevented that.